# Use time interval to update and delete rows based on now()

Tags: mysql, events

I am working on some game logic and I need a way to update a level when time runs out. Basically, there is a research table with columns as such:

```
research_time_id    
research_started    
research_end   
active   
level
```

I need the level to be set to level+1 when research_ended is sooner then NOW().

I know how to write the UPDATE statement. My question is should I run this through mysql eventscheduler? should I run it every second? Is that too often? What is optimum in a scalable environment? This table could have many rows in it.

Comment: Arguably, the more correct approach is to test research_ended < NOW() ... or > ... or >= etc... deriving the correct value in your live queries, and to have that column indexed.  A separate column like this introduces potential errors in tolerance, but worse, appears to violate 3rd normal form, which is a bit of a red flag, and sets you up for anomalies where one attribute disagrees with what another attribute implies.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - That is what I am testing. I am confused by your comment. `researched_started` is merely a display device and not used in the mechanics. Comparing `research_ended` to NOW is my intention. The problem is the `level` column is used in other game mechanics to improve out comes for the player. I need this level to update as soon as time runs out. Even if the player is afk or not logged in at all.